# MongoDB / Doctrine ODM / SF4.1 : Aggregate as equivalent of Inner Join

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, doctrine-odm

I try to aggregate documents in order to return an array with values of several documents.

Here is my Model Circuit :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Mongo\Field(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;
/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @Mongo\ReferenceMany(targetDocument=Truck::class, inversedBy="circuits")
 */
protected $trucks;
/**
 * @var Stand
 *
 * @Mongo\ReferenceOne(targetDocument=Stand::class, inversedBy="circuits")
 */
protected $stand;
```

My Truck Model :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Mongo\Field(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $code;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Mongo\Field(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;
/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @Mongo\ReferenceMany(targetDocument=Circuit::class, inversedBy="trucks")
 */
protected $circuits;
```

My Stand Model :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Mongo\Field(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @Mongo\ReferenceMany(targetDocument=Truck::class, inversedBy="stand", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $trucks;
```

My problem is that I am not able to return a circuit with the stand and the truck's code :

My current output looks like that :

```
{
"_id" : "5bcdd97724083a098f30bdcc",
"nom" : "First Circuit",
"stand" : {
    "$ref" : "stand",
    "$id" : "5bcdd97424083a098f30bd85",
    "$db" : "my_db"
},
"trucks" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "truck",
        "$id" : "5bcdda0324083a099745b22e",
        "$db" : "my_db"
    }
],
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-10-22T14:06:47.541Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-22T14:06:47.541Z")
```

}

However I'd like to have an output like that :

```
    {
"_id" : "5bcdd97724083a098f30bdcc",
"name" : "First Circuit",
"stand" : {
    "name": "Stand name"
},
"trucks" : [ 
    {
        "code": "Truck code 1"
    },
    {
        "code": "Truck code 2"
    }
],
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-10-22T14:06:47.541Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-22T14:06:47.541Z")
```

}

Currently, I've set a first query on circuit document like that :

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->find()
        ->select(['name', 'trucks'])
        ->field('stand.id')
            ->equals($id)
        ->field('date')
            ->gte($startOfDay)
            ->lte($endOfDay)
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->eagerCursor(true);
```

For having a better understanding, I try to have the equivalent of this SQL request :

```
SELECT circuit.name, truck.code, stand.name FROM circuit INNER JOIN truck (I do not set the ON clause, because here is a nested document) INNER JOIN stand WHERE date >= '2018-10-22 00:00:00' AND date <= '2018-10-22 23:59:59';
```

Could you help me to set the correct mongo/doctrine query please ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/priming-references.html

Comment: First and foremost, you need to use aggregation builder (`->createAggregationBuilder()` described in https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/aggregation-builder.html#aggregation-builder), not query builder.